# Can you spawn a child process written in a different language than a Python or PHP server, like you would with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js, child-process

What are the Python (Tornado/Flask/etc) or Apache/PHP ways of spawning a child process to run a script written in a different programming language than Python or PHP, and communicate with the server over standard input and output?

I'm looking for the Python/PHP equivalent to Node.js "child_process" library. I'm a Node.js programmer trying to justify using it on our company's infrastructure, and one major perk for our industry (research science) is that I would be able to use scripts written in Python and R seamlessly with a Node.js server. Before I claim that we NEED Node.js to have this benefit I want to make sure you can't do the same with a Python or PHP based server.

I'm not quite sure how to search for this

Comment: of course you can: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: There are a few functions which allow you to run a command, e.g. `exec`, `shell_exec`, `proc_open`, `passthru`... just look through the docs http://php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of the spawning process isn't relevant to the language of the spawned process. This is not a feature of Node.JS, PHP, or Python, this is a feature of the operating system.

In python, for example, one uses calls from the `subprocess` module. Here is an example of a Python script calling a C program:

```
files = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/ls', '/tmp'])
```

Comment: Is it easy to communicate through standard input and output with the spawned processes in Python and PHP?

Comment: @Leif. For php maybe have a good look at CLI, pipes and sockets with proc_open etc as has been mentioned above. A whole bunch of fun but works well esp on nix servers.

Comment: Yes, it is fairly easy to communicate through standard input and output with the spawned process in Python.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping this would be ridiculously hard with the other stacks so the directors would be forced to go with my pick of a technology stack. Looks like I'll have to stick to other rational, thanks everyone though!